# XSLT 1.0: using EXSLT to get element name according to substring

Tags: xslt, exslt

I have the following XML and I want to get only the element names that start with "MBH":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GenericRecs>
<GenericRecord>
    <record>
        <MBH1/>
    </record>
    <record>
        <BAL1/>
    </record>
    <record>
        <MBH2/>
    </record>
    <record>
        <BAL2/>
    </record>
    <record>
        <PAY2/>
    </record>
    <record>
        <MBH3/>
    </record>
    <record>
        <BAL3/>
    </record>
    <record>
        <PAY3/>
    </record>
</GenericRecord>
</GenericRecs>
```

I have the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
version="1.0">

<xsl:variable name="x" select="ext:node-set(substring(local-name(//record/child::*),1,3)='MBH')"/>

<xsl:variable name="mbh">
    <xsl:for-each select="$x">
            <item>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:value-of select="local-name(.)"/>
                </xsl:copy> 
            </item>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$mbh"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But all I get is an error "Description: Can not convert #RTREEFRAG to a NodeList!"
I am using EXSLT but I do not understand why I would get that error.

Comment: From what I see none of the complicated things you do is necessary. It looks more like you're digging yourself into a hole there.

Comment: you are right, sometimes I just think to complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have the following XML and I want to get only the element names that start with "MBH":

What's wrong with

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//record/*[starts-with(name(), 'MBH')]" />
```

?

A few notes:

- Use `name()` rather than `local-name()` whenever possible. There are no namespaces in your input so there is no difference between them anyway.
- the `child::` axis is the default. `child::*` is equivalent to `*`.
- If you can do anything about it, change the input. Having `<xyz1>` through `<xyz3>` is not very clever, unless `<xyz3>` actually is completely different from `<xyz1>` (instead of merely being *"the third `<xyz>`"*).
  In that case `<xyz num="1">` would be sensible. If they are completely different, they should not have a similar name.

Comment: Hello Tomalak, thank you for getting me into the right direction. I found your apply-templates only returns "true" for the found elements. I changed it to  <xsl:template match="//record/*[starts-with(name(), 'MBH')]">
   <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
 </xsl:template> and it works well.

Comment: @Peter Glad I helped, but I have a gut feeling that you're still doing it wrong. Why are you using `node-set()` at all? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: no, no, it looks much simpler now: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 version="1.0">

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
 
 <xsl:template match="//record/*[starts-with(name(), 'MBH')]">
   <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
 </xsl:template>
 
</xsl:stylesheet>`

Comment: it only gives me a string of the 3 MBH... elements but that is fine.

Comment: @Peter: Ah, I see. Yeah that's not looking too bad.